# Entendendo melhor a contagem do max_user_connections no MySQL

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, asp, iis

1. Se em uma página eu tenho conexão e consulta a mais de um banco de dados vai contar como duas conexões
2. E se for o mesmo banco de dados, mas tiver várias consultas (select) vai contar como várias conexões ativas?
3. Porque no show proccesslist ficam ativas (sleep)?  todas as conexões ficar em sleep por um mesmo período de tempo? Tenho a impressão que são tempos diferentes, e porque elas acabam ficando como sleep?

Answer (score 2):

Vou enumerar de maneira simples:

1. Apesar do nome o `max_user_connections` não esta relacionado a usuários, o PHP é o "client-side" do mysql, logo cada conexão com as APIs como:

   - `mysqli_connect`
   - `new PDO`

   É que contam para este numero, claro que isto eu não estou falando de conexões persistentes (que é outro assunto)
2. > Se em uma página eu tenho conexão e consulta a mais de um banco de dados vai contar como duas conexões

   Não, como disse no primeiro, a conexão esta relacionada a partir do ponto que realmente se conecta com as APIs, no momento de executar as querys a conexão já esta estabelecida, claro que existem situações de perda de conexão o qual você pode tratar e tentar reconectar, por exemplo:

   [`mysqli::ping()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.ping.php) é um exemplo de função que pode ser usado para checar o estado de uma conexão já feita antes de executar uma query, pois se a página tem um script longo existe uma possibilidade da conexão ter se perdido por coisas como instabilidade de conexão do lado do servidor que se comunica com o servidor mysql, com isto você poderia criar uma função recursiva que se acaso perdesse o "sinal" tentaria executar a query novamente, ou poderia checar até o erro da query com `mysqli::$errno` (no momento não sei qual o numero do erro de conexão perdida, irei editar esta parte da resposta em breve)
3. > Porque no show proccesslist ficam ativas (sleep)? todas as conexões ficar em sleep por um mesmo período de tempo? Tenho a impressão que são tempos diferentes, e porque elas acabam ficando como sleep?

   Conexões `sleep` são as conexões que estão abertas, mas não estão executando de fato, eu não tenho certeza, mas creio que mesmo ao executar `mysqli::close()` (ou APIs equivalente) talvez a conexão não é totalmente finalizada, quem resolve isto creio que talvez seja o programa principal do PHP, mesmo depois que o teu script já fechou a conexão (não tenho certeza, pode ser que realmente ele feche e aguarde fechar), vou confirmar isto depois, mas só para voltar ao foco, se uma página PHP faz uma conexão com o banco, mas você não executa nada, nem uma query se quer muito provavelmente ele será um *sleep* na lista, eu te dou a sugestão de talvez implementar o seu proprio script, que só conecta se executar uma query ao menos, eu fiz isto, diminuiu 30% de conexões desnecessárias que eu tinha, um exemplo bem simplório:

   ```
   class Banco
   {
        private $conexao;
        private $host;
        private $user;
        private $pass;
        private $db;

        private function conectar()
        {
              //Previne conectar duas vezes
              if ($this->conexao) return true;

              $this->conexao = new mysqli($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->db);

              //Retorna true em caso de conexão bem sucedida, false caso contrário
              return !!$this->conexao;
        }

        // salva as variaveis para a conexão
        public function __construct($host, $user, $pass, $db)
        {
             $this->host = $host;
             $this->user = $user;
             $this->pass = $pass;
             $this->db   = $db;
        }

        // só fecha a conexão se existe uma conexão aberta
        public function close()
        {
             if ($this->conexao) $this->conexao->close();
        }

        // Qualquer método que usar do mysqli será executado a partir daqui e será aplicando no $this->conexao
        public function __call($metodo, $argumentos)
        {
             if ($this->conectar()) {
                  return call_user_func_array($metodo, $argumentos);
             }

             //Retorna
             return false;
        }

        // Qualquer proriedade/variavel do mysqli que quiser acessar será a partir daqui e será aplicando no $this->conexao->$propriedade, retornando somente o valor
        public function __get($propriedade) {
            return $this->conexao->$propriedade;
        }
   }
   ```

   No uso ficaria assim:

   ```
   $banco = new Banco('1.1.1.1', 'foo', 'senha', 'banco');

   //O banco só conecta neste momento
   $banco->query('SELECT ...');
   ```

   Ou seja, se executar `new Banco` em uma página, mas não houver querys, então não irá se conectar, o que vai ajudar a poupar muito o servidor. Entenda que este código é apenas um exemplo, dá pra fazer isso de inumeras formas, e não estou afirmando que a forma acima é a ideal, é só um exemplo ilustrativo para entender

Comment: o ponto 3 tb é minha dúvida, estou quase certo que fechei todas as conexões, mas ainda assim vejo os sleep. Eu mudei de host e o antigo o max_user_connections era 100, nesse é 25; e isso está dando muitos problemas qdo nos horários de picos e ainda tem robots indexando.

Comment: Caro @SuperMax justamente pq mesmo conectado talvez nem tudo morra, e podem haver paginas que conectam sem precisar conectar, ou seja quando não tem querys para serem executadas, por isso sugeri a implementação de script que só conecta quando realmente vai executar algo

Comment: o estranho é que acompanhando SHOW PROCESSLIST pelo Phpadmim, as consultas feitas pelo php, não ficam como sleep. Por isso queria saber se todas ficam como sleep e pelo mesmo tempo, e/ou o que faz com elas fiquem ativas como sleep.

Comment: pelo que acompanhei os Sleep estão durando cerca de 70 segundo, mas se são reutilizados, ai são zerados e começam a contagem até 70 segundos novamente.

Comment: @SuperMax 70 segundos, isto é estranho, deve ser algum programa que esta usando o mysql, ou o proprio phpmyadmin que esta usando e esta exibindo isto para ti. Não sou chegado ao phpmyadmin, hoje uso o DBeaver, que além de suportar muitos bancos é rápido, bem organizado e com muitas ferramentas bem mais otimizadas que as do phpmyadmin, .... só pra constar phpmyadmin é só uma ferramenta, ela não é ligada ao mysql, e o mysql não precisa dela para nada :) ... só estou comentando pq as vezes as pessoas confundem.

Comment: @SuperMax esta usando asp ou asp.net?

Comment: estou usando asp